# After logging in and creating session in asp and mysql, how to change navbar?

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

So I am working on a project and creating shopping site in classic asp and mysql, I have succesfully connected database and succesfully created working register and login page but when I logged i couldn't change the navbar like you know replacing "Log in" with "Log out" or replacing "Register" with "My Account". Can anyone help me? Here is my codes

```
    baglan.asp <%    

     mysql_server = "localhost"
     mysql_user = "root"
     mysql_pass = ""
     mysql_db = "favcategorize"

     Connection_DSN= "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Stmt=SET NAMES 'utf8'; SERVER="&mysql_server&"; UID="&mysql_user&"; pwd="&mysql_pass&";db="&mysql_db&";"
     Set Baglanti= Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
     Baglanti.Open Connection_DSN
    
%>
```

///Seperate Files///

```
<!--#include file="baglan.asp"-->
<%
'her girişte sessionlar biter bu şekilde
session.abandon
if not isempty(Request.Form("submit")) then
    islem=Request.Form("submit")
    if islem="Giriş Yap" then
        email=Request.Form("email")
        password=Request.Form("password")
        if email="" OR password="" then
            mesaj="<span style='color:red'>Alanları doldurunuz</span>"
        else
            query="SELECT * FROM uye WHERE email='"&email&"'"
            Set kullanicisql=Baglanti.Execute(query)
            Do Until kullanicisql.eof
                 uyekontrol=1
                 kullanicisql.MoveNext
            Loop
            if uyekontrol=1 then
                query1="SELECT * FROM uye WHERE email='"&email&"' AND password='"&password&"'"
                Set kullanicipassword=Baglanti.Execute(query1)
                Do Until kullanicipassword.eof
                     passwordkontrol=1
                     'kullanicitip=kullanicipassword("2")
                     kullanicipassword.MoveNext
                Loop
                if passwordkontrol=1 then
                    Session.Timeout=10
                    Session("uye")=email                
                else
                    mesaj="<span style='color:red'>Parolanızı yanlış girdiniz</span>"
                end if
            else
                mesaj="<span style='color:red'>Bu email adresine ait kullanıcı bulunamadı</span>"
            end if
        
        end if
    elseif islem="kayit" then
        Response.Redirect "kayit.asp"
    end if
end if
%>
```

/////

```
<!--#include file="ustgiris.asp"-->
<!--#include file="baglan.asp"-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FavCategorize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="myBodyClass">
<%
if Session("uye")="" then
%>   
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item mainpage">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.asp">Anasayfa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="giris.asp">Giriş Yap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="kayit.asp">Kayıt Ol</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">

    <form method="post" action="giris.asp">
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" class="kayitInput" placeholder="E-Posta"><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" class="kayitInput" placeholder="Parola"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Giriş Yap" class="kayitButon btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-block"><br>
    </form>
 
    <%
else
    Response.Redirect "index.asp"

end if
    Response.write mesaj
%>
</div>




    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

///////

```
<!--#include file="ustgiris.asp"-->
<!--#include file="baglan.asp"-->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FavCategorize</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<%
if Session("uye")=email then %>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item mainpage">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.asp">Anasayfa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="hesabim.asp">Hesabım</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="logout.asp">Çıkış Yap</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>"
    <% else %>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center">
        <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item mainpage">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.asp">Anasayfa</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">İletişim</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hakkımızda</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="giris.asp">Giriş Yap</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="kayit.asp">Kayıt Ol</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <% end if
%>
```

Comment: So many bad practices here I wouldn’t know where to start. Storing login state in a `Session` is a basic concept in Classic ASP (which has been around for 20+ years now) and is covered already on [so] many times. Also, consider maintaining the connection to the database for as short a time as possible rather then for the duration of the page.

Comment: well I'm going to use classic asp in my entire life only on this project and yes this is an old coding lang and there isn't much source to look into so I just wanted to ask here if you do have a problem with that just report the question

Comment: That’s my point, there are lot’s of existing questions and answers on [so] about this issue, you just have to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your login scrip, set a session variable to indicate a login has happened, then on the menu page do something like:
(**edit note - don't put this into your code if you plan to use the other 2 sections instead .. and you are I believe)**

```
IF Session("uye") = 1 THEN
   response.write("LOGOUT")
ELSE
   respone.write("LOGIN")
END IF
```

And put that code in the menubar where you want it to either say LOGIN or LOGOUT for example.   You could also maybe pass the login state as a string in the variable to do something like this if you like:
(**EDIT NOTE - put this at the start of the script just after the `<BODY>`tag**)

```
    dim logstate
    IF Session("uye") = 1 THEN
       logstate = 1
    ELSE
       logstate = 0
    END IF
```

Then after that variable is set up this code(obviously you will need to include your other code as well, but this is to show you that you should be able to use an if/then to check a variable and then display HTML content via ASP.

```
IF logstate = 1 THEN
   response.write("<a class='nav-link' href='logout.asp'>LOGOUT</a>")
ELSE
   response.write("<a class='nav-link' href='login.asp'>LOGIN</a>")
END IF
```

If you use both of the last 2 scripts together, it will display the logout html or the login html based on the session variable code we did before this.

I think you are doing something with the variable called uye which tracks the login state correct?  So, if you use that with my code it should display the appropriate login or logout depending on what is set in that session variable, does that make sense?

Update notes - changed it to uye variable, and made it numeric instead of a string.  Did you post the login script too cause maybe its not passing the variable?

If you do this code at the end of the script what does it say, is it a 1 or is it nothing?  If its nothing, I suspect the session variable isn't getting set, I would like to see the login script perhaps if that is the case.  Try this:

```
response.write("uye is " & Session("uye") & "<br>")
```

Comment: well i did something similiar before then I did what you said I should do and yes I check email and password first then if they are correct i declare variable called uye=1 then I used it with your code but it didn't work

Comment: ok i will try to edit it to fit your code with uye = 1 if that is how you want to do it instead of a string.

Comment: Try that, and also when you say it doesn't work, what does it display?  Also included code to check to see if the variable is being set.  But in your login.asp script, after it does the checks, you are doing something like this:
IF password = password and email = email THEN
   Session("uye") = 1
ELSE
   'nothing else for now
END IF

Comment: nothing happens, on the navbar login and register links just disappear

Comment: dim logstate
    IF Session("uye") = 1 THEN
       logstate = 1
    ELSE
       logstate = 0
    END IF /// Do I put this code into ustgiris.asp or giris.asp? and i added response.write("uye is " & Session("uye") & "<br>") this and it shows the correct email on database and i also change the session("uye")=1 into session("uye")=email then before this response.write("uye is " & Session("uye") & "<br>") i added if Session("uye")=email then and it showed the email

Comment: That’s a lot of explanation for something that is a basic concept in Classic ASP. Maintaining login state in Classic ASP is not a new concept and is already covered on [so] many times over the years.

Comment: Technically nothing is a new concept in ASP Classic, but if you are going to comment that, why not offer some constructive links to those prior instances instead of just pointing it out?

Comment: I did, I flagged it as a duplicate as you should have.

Comment: no no .. not flag it for duplicate, FIND the actual other articles dealing with this, post that are duplicate, I know its easy to flag things versus come up with code, so do a search too with your flag so that you do actual work as well.

Comment: No, flagging the content as a duplicate is the correct thing to do. Storing information the `Session` object to persist it across page loads is nothing new a discussed many times. Feel I’m just repeating myself now. You're new so i’ll just say please spend some time reading through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that should point you in the right direction when it comes to choosing questions to answer.